# load buffer raw pixels to imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, scale, image-manipulation, pixel

I would like to load a buffer of pixels in order to scale it using ImageMagick.
I'm getting an exception when I call the constructor, here is my code :

```
BYTE *Duplication::scaleBufferImageMagick(unsigned char *data, int width, int height) {
BYTE *buffer = nullptr;

try {
    Magick::Image image(width, height, "BGRA", Magick::StorageType::CharPixel, data);
    Magick::Image scaled = image;

    scaled.resize("1280x720");

    int w = scaled.columns();
    int h = scaled.rows();

    Magick::Quantum *pixels = scaled.getPixels(0, 0, w, h);
}
catch (Magick::Exception &error) {
    TRACE("ERROR -> ", error.what()); //nothing on error.what()
}

return buffer;
}
```

The exception is not explicit at all :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7687A9F2 in myexe.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Magick::ErrorOption at memory location 0x08EDEE34.
```

Can someone tell me how to do this process... As it should be very simple ...

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: There is no message at all.

Comment: How is the buffer created?

Comment: I'm getting from a screenshot of my desktop with acquirenextframe function.

Comment: How do you know the buffer is BGRA? You could read from the file `screenshot:` instead.

Comment: AcquireNextFrame give an ouput in D3D11Texture2D object. From this object I can get the buffer of pixels. The format of pixels is : BGRA... That is the buffer I'm passing on my function "scaleBufferImageMagick"

Answer (score 0):

The storage type should not be undefined. If `*data` is `unsigned char` then you should load the stream with `Magick::StorageType::CharPixel`.

```
Magick::Image image(1920, 1080, "BGRA", Magick::StorageType::CharPixel, data);
```

Comment: Still same problem... I tried every possibilites.. Post edited !

Comment: Do you have any other solution ?